# Routes transitions doesnt not work in nuxt.js + electron.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, electron, nuxt.js

I use vue.js + nuxt.js + electron

in global.css i adding next code

```
.page-enter-active, .page-leave-active{
    transition: all 0,5s;
}


.page-enter, .page-leave-active{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

but transitions effects does not work
how to solve a problem?

Comment: Just the first animation when you open your application or all animations?